# JMS not working with activemq in mule esb

Tags: activemq-classic, mule, mule-studio

I am using mulestudio.
I wish to insert the values in jms queue using mule studio .But i have done all required changes but queue is not creating in activemq
I am using activemq-5.8.0 version even i added jar file 
my config is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd">
    <jms:activemq-connector name="jmsConnector"  
        brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616"

        maxRedelivery="30"
        disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="true"

        acknowledgementMode="CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE"

        persistentDelivery="true" doc:name="Active MQ" password="admin" username="admin" validateConnections="true">
    </jms:activemq-connector>    <flow name="Acivemqdemo_flow" doc:name="Acivemqdemo_flow">
            <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8087" doc:name="HTTP"/>
            <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="queue" connector-ref="jmsConnector" doc:name="JMS">
                <jms:transaction action="NONE"/>
            </jms:outbound-endpoint>
        </flow>
</mule>
```

i have done as per docs but unable get the expected queue 
my error log is

```
INFO  2014-01-03 16:20:09,890 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting connector: jmsConnector
INFO  2014-01-03 16:20:09,911 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting model: _muleSystemModel
INFO  2014-01-03 16:20:09,912 [main] org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager: Starting flow: Acivemqdemo_flow
INFO  2014-01-03 16:20:09,913 [main] org.mule.processor.SedaStageLifecycleManager: Starting service: Acivemqdemo_flow.stage1
INFO  2014-01-03 16:20:09,919 [main] org.mule.transport.http.HttpConnector: Registering listener: Acivemqdemo_flow on endpointUri: http://localhost:8087
INFO  2014-01-03 16:20:09,924 [main] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default response transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.MuleMessageToHttpResponse
INFO  2014-01-03 16:20:09,938 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'null'. Object is: HttpMessageReceiver
INFO  2014-01-03 16:20:09,940 [main] org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver: Connecting clusterizable message receiver
ERROR 2014-01-03 16:20:09,942 [main] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Address already in use (java.net.BindException)
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Address already in use (java.net.BindException)
  java.net.PlainSocketImpl:-2 (null)
2. Address already in use (java.net.BindException) (org.mule.transport.ConnectException)
  org.mule.transport.http.HttpConnectionManager:73 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/transport/ConnectException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:353)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:336)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

INFO  2014-01-03 16:20:09,944 [main] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Exception caught is a ConnectException, attempting to reconnect...
INFO  2014-01-03 16:20:09,944 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Stopping connector: connector.http.mule.default
INFO  2014-01-03 16:20:09,945 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Stopping: 'null'. Object is: HttpMessageReceiver
ERROR 2014-01-03 16:20:09,946 [main] org.mule.transport.http.HttpConnector: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpConnector.disconnect(HttpConnector.java:542)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver.doDisconnect(HttpMessageReceiver.java:52)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractTransportMessageHandler.disconnect(AbstractTransportMessageHandler.java:251)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.disconnect(AbstractConnector.java:1656)
    at org.mule.exception.AbstractSystemExceptionStrategy.handleReconnection(AbstractSystemExceptionStrategy.java:97)
    at org.mule.exception.AbstractSystemExceptionStrategy.handleException(AbstractSystemExceptionStrategy.java:59)
    at org.mule.exception.AbstractSystemExceptionStrategy.handleException(AbstractSystemExceptionStrategy.java:77)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:148)
    at org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager.fireStartPhase(FlowConstructLifecycleManager.java:95)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.start(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:225)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager$RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:276)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:155)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:126)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:80)
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:120)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:94)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:90)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:72)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:64)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:255)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:147)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.start(ApplicationWrapper.java:107)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:48)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:127)
INFO  2014-01-03 16:20:09,948 [main] org.mule.transport.http.HttpConnector: Disconnected: HttpConnector
{
  name=connector.http.mule.default
  lifecycle=stop
  this=4f980c26
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[http]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}

INFO  2014-01-03 16:20:09,948 [main] org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver: Connecting clusterizable message receiver
ERROR 2014-01-03 16:20:09,948 [main] org.mule.retry.notifiers.ConnectNotifier: Failed to connect/reconnect: HttpConnector
{
  name=connector.http.mule.default
  lifecycle=stop
  this=4f980c26
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=false
  supportedProtocols=[http]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
. Root Exception was: null. Type: class java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR 2014-01-03 16:20:09,951 [main] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: null
INFO  2014-01-03 16:20:09,958 [main] org.mule.module.management.agent.WrapperManagerAgent: This JVM hasn't been launched by the wrapper, the agent will not run.
INFO  2014-01-03 16:20:09,969 [main] org.mule.module.management.agent.JmxAgent: Attempting to register service with name: Mule.acivemqjms:type=Endpoint,service="Acivemqdemo_flow",connector=connector.http.mule.default,name="endpoint.http.localhost.8087"
INFO  2014-01-03 16:20:09,969 [main] org.mule.module.management.agent.JmxAgent: Registered Endpoint Service with name: Mule.acivemqjms:type=Endpoint,service="Acivemqdemo_flow",connector=connector.http.mule.default,name="endpoint.http.localhost.8087"
INFO  2014-01-03 16:20:09,970 [main] org.mule.module.management.agent.JmxAgent: Registered Connector Service with name Mule.acivemqjms:type=Connector,name="connector.http.mule.default.1"
INFO  2014-01-03 16:20:09,970 [main] org.mule.module.management.agent.JmxAgent: Registered Connector Service with name Mule.acivemqjms:type=Connector,name="jmsConnector.1"
INFO  2014-01-03 16:20:09,972 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: Reload interval: 3000
INFO  2014-01-03 16:20:09,974 [main] org.mule.DefaultMuleContext: 
**********************************************************************
* Application: acivemqjms                                            *
* OS encoding: UTF-8, Mule encoding: UTF-8                           *
*                                                                    *
* Agents Running:                                                    *
*   Clustering Agent                                                 *
*   JMX Agent                                                        *
**********************************************************************
INFO  2014-01-03 16:20:09,974 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Started app 'acivemqjms'                                 +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

will you help for this and how to consume the message from mule give me any example doc

Answer (score 0):

the mule application cannot start it cannot connect to the http port 8087
it is most likely because you already have an instance running.

Try in order of esculation:

- hit the red button in the console window
- restart eclipse studio
- or if you need to close the eclipse studio, check if you have any java processes running other than activemq

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu use this kill the process and release the port.

```
fuser -k 80/tcp
```

replace 80 with port number you need to release.

In Mac, find and kill the PID with netstat.

Answer (score 0):

From your exception `java.net.BindException: Address already in use` , it seems your inbound address, port is already used by some other endpoint, either by some other Mule endpoint or any other external application.
Solution is, please check once if the port or address is used by other application.
To check, use the command `netstat` in the following ways to check your port from command prompt :- [Command line for looking at specific port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010631/command-line-for-looking-at-specific-port)