# Windows command for looking at specific port (Exactly)

Tags: regex, port, netstat

I am trying to determine what command I can use to check if a port is in use in Windows. I looked into [Command line for looking at specific port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010631/command-line-for-looking-at-specific-port) but none of the answer fits exactly what I am looking for.

For example I want to look whether port 500 is in use, I would use `netstat –an | findstr /r :500` but the results would appear to be

```
 TCP    0.0.0.0:5000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 TCP    [::]:5000              [::]:0                 LISTENING
 UDP    0.0.0.0:500            *:*
 UDP    127.0.0.1:50027        *:*
 UDP    [::]:500               *:*
```

That's not exactly what I want. I tried `netstat -an | findstr /r :500[\s]+` then nothing would show. Not sure how I can fix the query.

Any ideas?

Comment: also `netstat -an | findstr /r ":500 "` does not work

Comment: `netstat -an | findstr /r ":500[^0-9:]"` - 500 not followed by a number or a colon (to avoid it appearing in an IPv6 address)

Comment: Cool, it works. Any idea why the white space query with the `\s` won't work?

Answer (score 0):

`FindStr` command does not sport a full PCRE engine. So while the regular expression assertion `[^0-9:]` excludes numbers and a colon; the `\s` assertion simply escapes the letter `s` which will then match just the letter `s`. Whereas in PCRE `\s` represents whitespace.

See also this [findstr documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732459(v=ws.11).aspx) where it states `\x` matches a meta character but the document does not go into details about the other PCRE character classes like `\s`, `\w`, `\d` etc.

Try it for you self. From the your `c:\windows\system32` folder, issue the follow command

`dir | findstr \r "\s\s" | more`

You should receive a list of files which only have a double `s` like syscla**ss**.dll, or **ss**dpapi.dll... etc.