# how to check if port 8086 is listening, using a windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, port

Need to check if the process is running and the port that is being used(8086 and 8085) is in listening state, using a batch file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command line for looking at specific port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010631/command-line-for-looking-at-specific-port)

Comment: What part are you actually struggling with - and why a batch file?

Comment: send a message to that specific port and see if it can receive

Comment: Needed a batch file as i'm using it in an alert system, so that i will be notified if port is not listening

Answer (score 5):

```
netstat /o /a | find /i "listening" | find ":8086" >nul 2>nul && (
   echo 8086 is open
) || (
  echo 8086 is Not open
)
```

Comment: Thanks i did with findstr


netstat -o -n -a | findstr 8086
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 goto FOUND
echo port not found
goto FIN
:FOUND
echo port found
:FIN


Note: When an item is not found FINDSTR will return an %ERRORLEVEL% > 0
if item is found FINDSTR will return an %ERRORLEVEL% = 0

Comment: Also as a one-liner which is useful sometimes
netstat -nao | findstr "LISTENING" | findstr "0:8086" >nul 2>nul && (echo Port 8086 is open) || (echo Port 8086 is closed && exit 1)

Note the "exit 1" which returns an %ERRORLEVEL% > 0

Answer (score 1):

```
netstat -o -n -a | findstr 8086

if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 goto FOUND

echo port not found

goto FIN

:FOUND

echo port found

:FIN
```

Note: When an item is not found FINDSTR will return an %ERRORLEVEL% > 0
if item is found FINDSTR will return an %ERRORLEVEL% = 0

Comment: Nice, very simple.