# How to run a command in background in Windows GitHub Action

Tags: windows, batch-file, github, github-actions

I would like to serve local files through a web-server and execute some tests inside GitHub Action that runs Windows, but I cannot make it run server in the background

Here's my setup:

```
name: CI Windows

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - '*'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-2019

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: '3.x'

    - name: Test local api
      run: |
        cmd /c "START /b run-local-api-server.bat"
        curl -X GET "http://localhost:9195/README.md"
```

And `run-local-api-server.bat` script:

```
@echo off

python3 -m http.server 9195
```

The error I get is `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9195: Connection refused`.

Links:

- [full repository with this code](https://github.com/ribtoks/test-action-background)
- [failed run](https://github.com/ribtoks/test-action-background/runs/2248753184?check_suite_focus=true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check first if [adding a small pause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1672349/6309) would help.
And check the expected [port is listening](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47035543/6309).

```yaml
    - name: Test local api
      run: |
        cmd /c "START /b run-local-api-server.bat"
        ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul
        netstat -o -n -a | findstr 9195
        curl -X GET "http://localhost:9195/README.md"
```

Comment: Adding the pause helped

Comment: also, the way you proposed to add pause did not work on GitHub Action: `FileStream was asked to open a device that was not a file`

Comment: @Ribtoks I understand. I believe there are other ways to simulate a pause in a bat file though. Starting wiht the vanilla SLEEP (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48000823/6309)